# CSA temperature rating for electrical tape?

Tags: electrical

I've got an old roll of electrical whose inside has the text "CSA", "LR31971", and "NO.33546". I need to tape down heating cables, and the product sheet says to use CSA-approved tape rated to 80 Celsius. I tried googling the text above, but nothing I found provides information on whether the labelling represents a specific standard and temperature rating. Does the text actually provide enough information to look this up?

I could trot on down to the hardware store and buy more tape, and the temperature rating will be right on the packaging. What I'm trying to avoid is buying new tape for each and every job. All that leads to is an accumulation of hardly-used rolls of electrical tape. I cannot see anyone keeping meticulous track of which roll accompanies which packaging information, so once the tape is removed from the packaging, the details on the packaging is gone, for all practical purposes. That's why I was hoping that there is enough information on the inside of the roll to look this up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Listing files to the rescue!

Thankfully, CSA publishes that information in the [listing file](https://www.csagroup.org/testing-certification/product-listing/certificate/?cert=031971_0_000-9052-02) for your tape; for your specific part number, it's listed to 80°C, so you're good to go.  (Other types of tape under that listing file have higher ratings.)

P.S. if you're following along at home, you'll need to leave the LR off the file number, and leave the other fields in the search form unpopulated.

Comment: How does one navigate the right page given the numbers on the inside of the roll?  I googled and googled.

Comment: @user2153235 -- go to [CSA's website](https://www.csagroup.org) and click on "Product Listing" under the "Testing and Verification" menu

Comment: The closest thing I could find was [Testing and Certification / CSA Group Product Listing](https://www.csagroup.org/testing-certification/product-listing/).  I get a search form, so I tried searching for 33546 (one of the numbers on the inside of the roll) without success.  What information did you enter into which field?  For me, the question is what the labelling information represents, which plays heavily into how one might search for it (and that's assuming one gets to the right search form).

Comment: Try the **other** number....

Comment: I think it would be helpful to know the formal terms for these numbers so that a judgement call can be made about which fields to use on the search form.  Otherwise, I'm just randomly trying them, with and without the prefixes, e.g., "No.", "LR".  I haven't had any luck, so there is a key combination that I haven't hit.

Comment: @user2153235 -- the "LRxxxxx" is a *file number*, and is how CSA identifies a specific listing

Comment: That is one field that I tried, using both "LR31971" and "31971" (without quotes, that is).  I get "No active CSA Group records found".  Same with "NO.33546" and "33546".  Are you actually getting some results?  [Here](https://www.csagroup.org/testing-certification/product-listing) again is the search form I've found and am using. *PS: Just for laughs, I also saw a Proposal 65 warning on some of the components I'm using.  What a fiaso.*

Comment: @user2153235 make sure that you have the "Product Area" not set to something

Comment: That works!  Could you please update your answer to say that the LR prefix must be left out of the "file number", and that no other fields can be populated?  Thanks!